# Time.local parses invalid dates

Tags: ruby, time

I have a really hard time believing no one else has encountered this, but I have been googling for an hour. Very simple the Time Ruby 1.9 seems to be parsing invalid dates:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 pcp070211pcs:profile delwateo$ irb
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > Time.local(2011, 2, 31)    
 => 2011-03-03 00:00:00 -0500
```

Shouldn't this be throwing an exception of some time. Can someone point me in the right direction on this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug with Ruby (happens in 1.8 too). You can use `Date.civil` instead if you only need a `Date` object without time and it'll properly handle this:

```
Date.civil(2011,2,31)
# => ArgumentError: invalid date
```

Comment: Yeah we are seeing it in 1.9.3 as well. We have managed to code around this issue for now, but my real question is why? It seems such a basic thing to be just an unreported bugs

Comment: I think it's just a bug. Not unreported anymore: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5988